# Javascript object as a type of mini database?

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, object

Is it possible to use a JavaScript object as a type of mini database? I often find myself needing a kind of database structure when I'm coding in JS but it feels like overkill to use an actual database like MySQL (or similar).

As an example, let's say I need to structure this data as a JS object:

**Object idea:** Stuff to sell
**Items to sell:** The junk in the garage
**Object structure:** List all items including item ***name***, item ***condition***, and item ***value***

In order to make this into a JS object I would maybe write:

```
var stuffToSell = {};
```

Then my first item would maybe look like:

```
var stuffToSell = {
    item : "Coffee Maker",
    condition : "Good",
    price : 5
};
```

Now to me this seems like I'm on the right track, until I come to add another item and I end up having to use the properties `item`, `condition`, and `price` again in the same JS object — which feels wrong? — or is it?? At this point my brain keeps shouting the word "ARRAY!" at me but I just can't see how I can use an array inside the object, or an object inside an array to achieve what I want.

My end goal (in this simplified example) is to be able to then use object-oriented syntax to be able to access certain items and find out specific information about the item such as `price`, `condition` etc. For example if I want to know the price of the `"coffee maker"` I would like to write something like:

```
stuffToSell["coffee maker"].price
```

...and then the result above should be `5`.

I feel like I'm on the right track but I think I'm missing the array part? Could someone please tell me what I'm missing or maybe what I'm doing completely wrong! And also if it is wrong to have duplicate property names in the same JS object? For example, is it okay to have:

```
var stuffToSell = {
item : "Coffee Maker",
price : 5,
item : "Mountain Bike",
price : 10,
item : "26 inch TV",
price : 15
};
```

...it seems wrong because then how does JS know which `price` goes with which `item`??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track!

A lot of people will refer to what you're talking about as a `hash`.

Here's my suggested structure for you:

```
var store = {
        coffee_maker: {
                id: 'coffee_maker',
                description: "The last coffee maker you'll ever need!",
                price: 5,
        },
        mountain_bike: {
                id: 'mountain_bike',
                description: 'The fastest mountain bike around!',
                price: 10,
        },
        tv: {
                id: 'tv',
                description: 'A big 26 inch TV',
                price: 15,
        },
}
```

Having a structure like that will let you do this:

```
store.mountain_bike.price // gives me 10
```

#### Need an array instead, say for filtering or looping over?

`Object.keys` gives you an Array of all the object's keys in the store `['coffee_maker', 'mountain_bike', 'tv']`

```
// Now we just have an array of objects 
// [{id: 'coffee_maker', price: 5}, {id: 'mountain_bike', price: 10} ...etc]
var arr = Object.keys(store).map(el => store[el])
```

#### Need to just filter for items that are less than 10?

This will give us an array of products less than 10:

```
// gives us [{id: 'coffee_maker', price: 5}]
var productsUnder10 = arr.filter(el => el.price < 10)
```

These techniques can be chained:

```
var productsOver10 = Object.keys(store)
    .map(el => store[el])
    .filter(el => el.price > 10)
```

#### Need to add a product?

```
store['new_product'] = {
    id: 'new_product',
    description: 'The Newest Product',
    price: 9000,
}
```

Here's another way, which would be good to start getting used to.
This is a 'safe' way to update the store, read up on immutability in javascript to learn about it

```
store = Object.assign({}, store, {
    'new_product': {
        id: 'new_product',
        description: 'The Newest Product',
        price: 9000,
    }
})
```

...and another way, that you should also read up on and start using:
This is the object spread operator, basically just an easier way to work with immutable structures

```
store = {
    ...store,
    'new_product': {
        id: 'new_product',
        description: 'The Newest Product',
        price: 9000,
    }
}
```

### Resources

- [JavaScript Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Object and Array Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
- [Immutable Javascript using ES6 and beyond](https://wecodetheweb.com/2016/02/12/immutable-javascript-using-es6-and-beyond/)

Comment: You're a genius. You have answered every part of my question in detail and also given me so much useful information about how I can use JS objects to store and access information. I'm sure this will also help many other people who are in the same boat as me. I can only dream of having JavaScript knowledge as vast as yours! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @BenClarke! I stayed away from it because it's not necessarily related to this post, but what you're starting to edge on is commonly referred to as 'state management'. It's a very hot topic in the front-end JS community right now. The next level thing you'll wanna start looking into are "unidirectional data flow patterns", state management libraries like Redux, Vuex, and MobX etc. Here's a video to give you an idea of it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYkdrAPrdcw

Comment: Wow, thank you, that's really useful information. I think I may have heard of 'state management' as I've recently been dipping my toe into the scary and very *seemingly* deep oceans of Vue and React — but I can definitely say for certain that I haven't heard of 'unidirectional data flow patterns', but I'll definitely watch the video to find out more as I'm sure it's information that can only help me learn more about JavaScript and programming in general. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool. I'm a big fan of Vue, hit me up if you need any help. The React community mostly likes to use the Redux library, Angular uses NgRx, and Vue uses Vuex - all of those support unidirectional data flows. They are all implementations of Flux, which was mostly based on the Elm architecture. btw, out of all the front-end JS frameworks out there, I highly recommend Vue as the one to pick up if they are all new to you. It touches on the vast majority of what any of the other ones are doing (Angular, React, etc), but it's concepts and patterns are much easier to get up and running with.

Comment: That's interesting because it was Vue that did in fact seem the most intuitive and easiest to grasp when I looked into Vue, React and Angular, so I'll definitely continue down the Vue path and hopefully learn lots more about it. Thanks again for your much appreciated help and advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use  `json` or create an array of objects.If using a separate file to store the objects, first load the file. Use array filter method to get an new array which matches the filter condition , like you want to get the item with id 1. This will return an array of objects.

```js
var dict = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'coffee-mug',
    'price': 60
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'pen',
    'price': 2
  }
]

function getItemPrice(itemId) {
  var getItem = dict.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id === itemId
  });
  return getItem[0].price;
}

console.log(getItemPrice(1))
```

Comment: Thanks. So you've added the array part that I was missing which makes sense now I see how you've structured it. However, does that mean that in order to access an object in the array I have to use the array filter method? It's just that I'm not too familiar with arrays and how to sort/filter them so that's something that I'll maybe have to learn. I was hoping to access the data using simple object-oriented syntax like `stuffToSell["coffee maker"].price`. When I write it like this it seems so easy but for some reason I just can't organise the code in a way that allows me to use this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

JSON objects don't support repeated keys, so you need to set unique keys.

**Put an id as your key to group your items:**

```
var stuffToSell = {
  '1': {
    item: "Coffee Maker",
    price: 5
  },
  '2': {
    item: "Mountain Bike",
    price: 10
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Now you can access the item's price very fast.

## Look at this code snippet (Known Ids)

```js
var stuffToSell = {
  '1': {
    item: "Coffee Maker",
    price: 5
  },
  '2': {
    item: "Mountain Bike",
    price: 10
  },
  '3': {
    item: "26 inch TV",
    price: 15
  }
};

let getPrice = (id) => stuffToSell[id].price;

console.log(getPrice('1'));
```

See? the access to your items it's fast and your code follows a readable structure.

## Look at this code snippet (Item's name as key)

```js
var stuffToSell = {
  'Coffee Maker': {
    price: 5
  },
  'Mountain Bike': {
    price: 10
  },
  '26 inch TV': {
    price: 15
  }
};

let getPrice = (id) => stuffToSell[id].price;

console.log(getPrice('Coffee Maker'));
```

## Look at this code snippet (Item's name: price)

```js
var stuffToSell = {
  'Coffee Maker': 5,
  'Mountain Bike': 10,
  '26 inch TV': 15
};

let getPrice = (id) => stuffToSell[id];

console.log(getPrice('Coffee Maker'));
```

Comment: Thanks. So you're using ***nested*** objects? That's great as I think that's the part I was missing. And I see you've assigned an id to each one in order to give them each a unique key for easy access which is also something I hadn't done. However, what if I don't know the unique id/key and I just want to use the item name to find out the price? Is that possible using this method?

Comment: @ yes,  see the updated answer with two additional approaches.

Comment: Ah I see — that's a clever method using the item name as the key as it allows me to use the item name to access the relevant information like `price` and `condition` etc. It also prevents duplicate items from being entered as I've just noticed that my code editor warns me when I use a duplicate key in an object. I think this method pretty much does what I asked for, and you've helped me to understand JS objects a little better as well so thank you.